# Is it possible to turn off the silent mode programmatically in android?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to turn off the silent mode programmatically in Android?

Comment: @Mat, well, that question was for iPhone, this is for android. I doubt the answers to that question is helpful to the op.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Solution for you .

```
AudioManager am;
am= (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

//For Normal mode
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

//For Silent mode
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

//For Vibrate mode
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```

Comment: Is this answer still valid in 2013? I thought I read that this is no longer viable per some recent update.

Comment: Hello? Can I get an answer here?

Comment: Working in smasung, nexus, moto devices. bit not working on xiomi devices. any idea how to achieve in xiomi devices.

Comment: hello abhi....did you achieve it on xiomi devices?? if yes then please tell me. @Abhi

Comment: @JaydipKalkani: No.

Comment: You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39152607/7804719). @Abhi

Comment: what permission  is required for this?

Comment: A little update: as per documentation "From N onward, ringer mode adjustments that would toggle Do Not Disturb are not allowed unless the app has been granted Do Not Disturb Access." -> which means you can't change Silent mode without asking for DnD permission.

Answer (score 10):

```
//SilentToNomal and NormalToSilent device Programatically
 final AudioManager mode = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
//Silent Mode Programatically
mode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

//Normal Mode Programatically
  mode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
```

Answer (score 6):

Solution:

```
AudioManager audio_mngr = (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audio_mngr .setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

Comment: how to make it reverse, after silent mode how to set back to normal mode.

Comment: @sandy try RINGER_MODE_NORMAL (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#RINGER_MODE_NORMAL) for it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible to turn off and on the silent mode programmatically below is the code :

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

for setting silent mode :

```
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

For normal mode :

```
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int normal = 2;
int vibrate = 1;
int silent = 0;
int RingerMode;
public static AudioManager AUDIOMANAGER;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    AUDIOMANAGER= (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (AUDIOMANAGER.getRingerMode() == normal) {
                    AUDIOMANAGER.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                    RingerMode = normal;
    } else if (AUDIOMANAGER.getRingerMode() == vibrate) {
                    AUDIOMANAGER.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                    RingerMode = vibrate;
                }
    //And after do all your jobs..... you can return to previous mode:
                    AUDIOMANAGER.setRingerMode(RingerMode);

}
```