# How to mute the beep sound for SpeechRecognizer?

Tags: android, audio, voice-recognition

This has been asked before, but no one seemed to have a solution: [Muting SpeechRecognizer's beep sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579197/muting-speechrecognizers-beep-sound)

Nevertheless, I still would like to know if anyone knows how to mute the beeping sound for SpeechRecognizer?

I create speechRecognizer object: *private SpeechRecognizer sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);*

And then in my class I instantiate the speechRecognizer like this

```
sr.setRecognitionListener(new listener());
Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);             
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getApplication()
        .getClass().getName());
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 6);
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "");
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 7000);
sr.startListening(i);
```

Anyone with any good ideas? I researched that I could create an object of AudioManager (*AudioManager mAudioManager*) and then using setStreamSolo(), I could mute the sound. But I am not sure how to implement this. I added it to my instantiation code for speechRecognizer and nothing happened. Is this something I should call from my main class?

```
mAudioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've got to do what I put on the following link:
[Muting the Google voice recognition beep sound](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734868/muting-the-google-voice-recognition-beep-sound/37809750#37809750)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Aww I would comment but I don't have the rep. However I would like to help.

Have you seen this:

[Continues Speech Recognition beep sound after Google Search update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701432/continues-speech-recognition-beep-sound-after-google-search-update)

[Is it possible to turn off the silent mode programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699603/is-it-possible-to-turn-off-the-silent-mode-programmatically-in-android)

[Mute the global sound in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895882/mute-the-global-sound-in-android)

It seems to me that the code is different depending on the android version - as stated in the first link, **Google switched the output of the 'beep' to the media stream**.

I am guessing one of those questions will have the solution. If so please post what you have done, as you stated many people seem to be having the problem.

My guess would be:

```
//mute audio

AudioManager amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, true);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);


//unmute audio

AudioManager amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, false);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, false);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
```

I imagine this answer from Witness applications user will work. Credit goes to:  @WitnessApplications

Also the scope of this would be **before you startListening(i);**

Comment: I think it is sufficient to mute STREAM_MUSIC and STREAM_SYSTEM (since API level 23 you should use AudioManager.setStreamVolume to silence a stream, by saving its previous status, in order to reset it to its original value when you want to unmute)

Comment: Massimo, you are right. and I will add, be very carefull when you play with the setStreamMute it may lock the phone in this mode, be very sure you relerase it properly.

Comment: Since `setStreamMute` is now deprecated, we could use `amanager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0);` or `amanager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.ADJUST_TOGGLE_MUTE, 0);`

Answer (score 3):

Even I find it annoying, especially when you have your app running in background.

Here is what how I worked around it in JAVA:

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);           
audio.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE,AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

Now this mutes the active stream, and most of the times(99/100) it turns out to be the music stream. So basically it mutes it and then beep disappears.

In my case I have added an event to do this based on my mood so I keep switching between ADJUST_UNMUTE and ADJUST_MUTE time to time. So far it is working for me.

But even I am looking for a better solution where it mutes just the beep not the whole stream.

Hope this helps some one.

Edit: I found out a better way than this which always mutes the Music stream.

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0,  AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

And to unmute do:

```
audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

Comment: this solution doesn't work for me, it doesn't mute the music stream at all

Answer (score 1):

With the solution above from Mark, you will have a crash with the following description:

```
Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=65736, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to change Do Not Disturb state
```

If you just want to mute the beep sound for speech recognizer, you just have to mute the `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC`.

In Kotlin, it looks like this for me:

```
object AudioUtils {

    @JvmStatic fun muteAudio(shouldMute: Boolean, context: Context)
    {
        val audioManager: AudioManager = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
        val muteValue = if (shouldMute) AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE else AudioManager.ADJUST_UNMUTE
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, muteValue, 0)
    }

}
```

Comment: requieres API level 23

Answer (score 0):

For public interest, I want to post an updated to this thread. The year is 2023. I am unable to find any method yet added that will suppress this awful bleeping. However, it can be suppressed, as others have indicated by  muting the notification stream. (Note that this appears to be different than mentioned in some of the older answers to this question.) I achieve the effect thus:

```
audioManager = (AudioManager) getReactApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

// to mute:
priorStreamVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(
    AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION
);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(
    AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION,
    0,
    AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE
);

// to unmute:
audioManager.setStreamVolume(
    AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION,
    priorStreamVolume,
    AudioManager.FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES
);
```

The flags I used may or may not be relevant to your own situation.